# How can I include file content to html head section in html?

Tags: html, file

I have this _head.html file:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Weboldal modulokból</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
```

How can I insert the content of _head.html file into < head > tag of my index.html?

This was my solution:

```
<head><link rel="import" href="_head.html"></head>
```

but it was a wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

HTML Imports are a feature that works natively only in Google Chrome. Support for HTML Imports in Google Chrome has been available since version 31, but it requires manual enabling. For further details, you can refer to the official documentation on MDN Web Docs.

So using the Link tag should not work anymore. Example Below :

```
<link rel="import" href="/path/to/some/import.html" />
```

Instead Please try to do it in php. Here is a simple example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Basic HTML Imports</title>
    <!-- Pull in our blog post example -->
    <?php require('blog-post.html'); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Make sure your index file is named Index.php, you can check the screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]